# Hyperlink is not getting highlighted when translating from English to French/German in swift

Tags: ios, swift, hyperlink, localization, nsattributedstring

I have a UILabel with hyperlink text.
Here is the code:

```
 let termsText = NSLocalizedString("To continue using this feature, please accept the Terms & Conditions", bundle: Bundle.terms, comment: "Continue")
        let linkText = NSLocalizedString("Terms & Conditions", bundle: Bundle.terms, comment: "Terms")
        termsLabel.setAttributedTextWithLinks(stringForAttributedText: termsText,
                                                           linksText: [linkText], boldFont: false,
                                                           underlined: false,
                                                           fontSize: 14,
                                                           textColor: UIColor(named: "Charcoal",
                                                                              in: Bundle(for: ViewController.self),
                                                                              compatibleWith: nil) ?? .black,
                                                           linkColor: UIColor(named: "Blue",
                                                                              in: Bundle(for: ViewController.self),
                                                                              compatibleWith: nil) ?? .blue,
                                                           paragraphStyle: nil) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.navigateToTermsAndConditionsVC()
        }
```

And this is the attributedString code:

```
func setAttributedTextWithLinks(stringForAttributedText: String, linksText: [String], boldFont: Bool = false, underlined: Bool = false, fontSize: CGFloat = 14.0, textColor: UIColor = UIColor(named: "Carbon", in: Bundle(for: UILabelWithLink.self), compatibleWith: nil) ?? .black, linkColor: UIColor = UIColor(named: "Blue", in: Bundle(for: AlertViewController.self), compatibleWith: nil) ?? .blue, paragraphStyle: NSParagraphStyle? = nil, linkTapped: @escaping (UInt) -> Void) {
        font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: boldFont ? .semibold : .regular)
        let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: textColor, NSAttributedString.Key.font: font] as [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]
        var linkAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: linkColor, NSAttributedString.Key.font: font] as [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]
        if underlined {
            linkAttributes[NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle] = 1
        }
        setAttributedTextWithLinks(stringForAttributedText: stringForAttributedText, textAttributes: textAttributes, isTextBold: boldFont, linksText: linksText, linkAttributes: linkAttributes, isLinkBold: boldFont, paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle, linkTapped: linkTapped)
    }
```

This is the code for setAttributedTextWithLinks():

```
func setAttributedTextWithLinks(stringForAttributedText: String, textAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any], isTextBold: Bool, linksText: [String], linkAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any], isLinkBold: Bool, paragraphStyle: NSParagraphStyle?, linkTapped: @escaping (UInt) -> Void) {
        self.linkTapped = linkTapped
        cachedLinksText = linksText
        let nsstringForAttributedText = stringForAttributedText as NSString

        var textAttributesVar = textAttributes
        var linkAttributesVar = linkAttributes
        updateAttributesForAsianCharacters(attributes: &textAttributesVar, isBold: isTextBold)
        updateAttributesForAsianCharacters(attributes: &linkAttributesVar, isBold: isLinkBold)

        let mutableAttributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringForAttributedText)
        let nonLinkComponents = stringForAttributedText.components(separatedBy: linksText)
        for regularText in nonLinkComponents {
            let range = nsstringForAttributedText.range(of: regularText)
            mutableAttributedText.addAttributes(textAttributesVar, range: range)
        }

        for linkText in linksText {
            let linkRange = nsstringForAttributedText.range(of: linkText)
            mutableAttributedText.addAttributes(linkAttributesVar, range: linkRange)
        }
        if paragraphStyle != nil {
            mutableAttributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle!, range: nsstringForAttributedText.range(of: stringForAttributedText))
        }

        attributedText = mutableAttributedText
        configureLinkTextForTouch()
        configureLayoutManagerTextStorageTextContainer()
    }
```

I have the Language change in the app. The problem is this translation works with hyperlink using the above code for Spanish and Chinese but its not working for French and German languages.
Is there something I should do specifically to these two languages?

Comment: It's unclear what does `setAttributedTextWithLinks(stringForAttributedText:textAttributes:...)` i guess the culprit is there... And if you debug, is `linkText` value correct in these languages? are they present in `termsText`?

Comment: `setAttributedTextWithLinks()` is I'm creating a hyperlink label with color of text. Yes its translating correctly and I can print in `linkText`.

Comment: What's the code of `setAttributedTextWithLinks(stringForAttributedText: stringForAttributedText, textAttributes: textAttributes, isTextBold: boldFont, linksText: linksText, linkAttributes: linkAttributes, isLinkBold: boldFont, paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle, linkTapped: linkTapped)`, I guess that's the issue, but we don't know what does that method...

Comment: The method is in the question below `And this is the attributedString code:`

Comment: So you are saying that this is method is calling itself? The last line of it, is calling it self? Then you have a infinite loop and a crash? That's not the same method to me. One has `isTextBold:` as one of its parameters...

Comment: @Larme sorry I got confused with the other method. I have added that code please check and let me know If you find anything missing?

Comment: Is `let linkRange = ` value correct? That's so much complicated code in my opinion, and if you have text with multiple links on the same "text" (like having twice "Terms & Conditions", it will work only on the first one. And I'm against using `UILabel` for typing on link, that's not done for that. Prefer `UITextView`.

Comment: `linkRange` for English is `{50,18}` but for German its `linkRange: {9223372036854775807, 0}` And I have the links only once.

Comment: It means it's not found... When it's the case, print `nsstringForAttributedText`  and `linkText`...

Comment: For English: **nsstringForAttributedText**: To continue using this feature, please accept the Terms & Conditions
**linkText**: Terms & Conditions
**linkRange**: {50, 18} 
for French: **nsstringForAttributedText**: Pour continuer à utiliser cette fonctionnalité, veuillez accepter les modalités et conditions
**linkText**: Modalités et conditions
**linkRange**: {9223372036854775807, 0}

Comment: There is an uppercase & a lower case in French that's why it's not found... `"Modalités et conditions"` != `"modalités et conditions"`

Comment: Oh ok. But how do I check for that condition specific to few languages?

Comment: Either fix it, but searching the correct text, or use the option to search case insensitively...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is on:

```
for linkText in linksText {
    let linkRange = nsstringForAttributedText.range(of: linkText)
    mutableAttributedText.addAttributes(linkAttributesVar, range: linkRange)
}
```

`linkRange` value when wrong is `{9223372036854775807, 0}`, which is `NSNotFound` (for the first one). You should check it.

In your French translation, you have `"... modalités et conditions ..."`, and you search `"Modalités et conditions"`, with an uppercase at start, so it's normal that it isn't found...

You are using [`range(of:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416849-range) and omitting the `options` parameter, using the default value. Instead use `.caseInsensitive` for `options`. parameter.

Now, this way of doing has a flow, if you have multiple links with the same word, `range(of:options:)` will return only the first occurence. You need to loop.

I find this work quite complex. If you have the hand on the translation, I'd go instead with:

```
"UseThisFeature" = "To continue using this feature, please accept the <link>%@</link>"
"TermAndConditions" = "Terms & Conditions"
```

It'd be simpler to replace afterwards and apply the effects. Where `<link>` & `</link>` can be any "marker/tag" you want.

Finally, I'd recommend to use `UITextView` for handling tags. It's much easier. `UILabel` aren't made for that. See [WWDC 2018: TextKit Best practices](https://www.wwdcnotes.com/notes/wwdc18/221/), slide 2. It's easy to male a `UITextView` looks like a `UILabel` for the final user.